# Typescript for groups of optional values as function parameters

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a function that takes any number of grouped values as parameters. I thought the best way to do this was to pass in arrays (but open to other options). Each array can have between 1-4 values that must match specific types. My attempt to code this looks like so:

```
const transition = (...properties: [string, number?, string?, number?][]): string => {
  // Do something
};
```

Usage could look like this:

```
transition(['color', 2]);
transition(['color', 2], ['background']);
transition(['color', 2], ['background', 2, 'ease']);
transition(['color', 2], ['background'], ['opacity', 3, 'ease']);
```

My compiler throws the error related to the `?` usage in the types:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected ","
```

If I remove the `?` I don't get the compile error but it then expects all values in the arrays to be passed.

Is there a simple solution to this?

Comment: Which version of Typescript do you use? Your code should be fine since 3.0(https://auth0.com/blog/typescript-3-exploring-tuples-the-unknown-type/).

Comment: [Works for me](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=const%20transition%20%3D%20(...properties%3A%20%5Bstring%2C%20number%3F%2C%20string%3F%2C%20number%3F%5D%5B%5D)%3A%20string%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%22%22%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atransition(%5B'color'%2C%202%5D)%3B%0D%0Atransition(%5B'color'%2C%202%5D%2C%20%5B'background'%5D)%3B%0D%0Atransition(%5B'color'%2C%202%5D%2C%20%5B'background'%2C%202%2C%20'ease'%5D)%3B%0D%0Atransition(%5B'color'%2C%202%5D%2C%20%5B'background'%5D%2C%20%5B'opacity'%2C%203%2C%20'ease'%5D)%3B).

Comment: @RomanKoliada I'm on v3.5.1. Strangely the I don't get the error in Visual Studio Code but I do when the compiler runs.

Comment: @Coop - What if you define the type separately (`type TransitionProps = [string, number?, string?, number?];`) and use that in the function signature (`const transition = (...properties: TransitionProps[]): string => { }`?

Comment: @Coop - *"Strangely the I don't get the error in Visual Studio Code but I do when the compiler runs."* That makes me think VSCode and `tsc` are out of sync, that you're using an older `tsc` for your actual compilation, something like that.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder type defined separately still throws the same error for me. How could my tsc be out of sync? I only install 1 version of Typescript through my package.json so not sure where a different version would be coming from...

Comment: Try to run `tsc -v`

Comment: @RomanKoliada `zsh: command not found: tsc`. It's only installed for the project through the package.json so not available as a global package. The version I'm using for the project is 3.5.1.

Comment: @Coop - I'd verify that by finding the exact copy of `tsc` being run and doing as Roman suggested (for instance, `node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc -v`), since v3.5.1 shouldn't have any problem with that code, and doesn't on my system (just checked).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Okay. Yes the exact local version is showing as 3.5.1.

Comment: @Coop - I think there must be a parsing problem prior to the code in the question, then, or somehow your project isn't running the copy of `tsc` you think it's running. The code above absolutely does work with `tsc` v3.5.1. Your best bet is to go through the [mcve] process; somewhere in there you'll find out what's going wrong. Good luck with it! Sounds like a pain. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Ok I'll have to break it down further and investigate. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score -2):

```
 // Declare a type for arguments 
export interface ITransitionProperties {
color: string,
value?: number,
type?: string,
value2?: number
}
// and use it in defining the type of argument
const transition = (ArgumentName: ITransitionProperties[]): string => {
// Do something
};
```

Comment: Wouldn't this change usage to an array of objects?